# Is this possible with GGPLOT2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that I need to model as mocked up in the graphic.
Both of the variations would be fine.Thought this was an easy task with ggplot2 to read the csv/xlsx file and plot it. It wasn't.
Not to mention the csv has a huge amount of datapoints.

Many thanks for any leads!

[image: []

Comment: Yes it is possible. There are many resources online to learn ggplot. This site is meant for coding problems, so next time you post give it a shot yourself and then try to seek help if you get a bug.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I know. As I received the task today, i wasnt aure what ro look for as i neither know the name of such plots nor of that Feature. Thus, i was hoping for any leads here.

Comment: With this, you would create the line plots and then create the straight lines over the plots with adobe illustrator. but you have 9 dates, but visualize 8 dates. and you have 2 different charts,  but nothing to facet them by in your dataset

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible in ggplot. If you copy and paste the following code into R:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- as.data.frame(spline(x = c(0, 3, 4, 5, 7.5, 9, 10, 11, 13, 16),
                           y = c(1, 4, 3.5, 2, 7, 5, 2, 3, 2.5, 4), n = 200))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(colour = "tomato", size = 1.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2, 10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 20)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 0, y = -0.5, yend = 9), size = 1.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 5, xend = 5, y = 0, yend = 9)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 9, xend = 9, y = 0, yend = 9)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 13, xend = 13, y = 0, yend = 9)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -0.5, xend = 16, y = 0, yend = 0), size = 1.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.5, xend = 16, y = 7.5, yend = 7.5)) +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(x = c(2.5, 7, 11, 14.5), y = 8, 
                              label = paste("Period", 1:4)),
            aes(label = label), size = 8) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 10, label = "Value"), size = 10, 
            check_overlap = TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 18, y = 0, label = "Date"), size = 10, 
            check_overlap = TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 3, y = 2, label = "Performance"), size = 6, 
            check_overlap = TRUE, color = "tomato") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray85"))
```

You get:

[image]

However, it's not clear whether you can apply any of this to your own data. Perhaps you can ask a new question with a clearer idea of what you're looking for and some reproducible data if you get stuck with it.